# Se retornar dados da base de dados o else fica inválido

Tags: javascript

Criei uma tabela para ser preenchida com `Datatables`. Se retornar dados da base de dados, pretendo que pegue na última data do campo data e preencha com a data do dia seguinte ao existente na base de dados, se não retornar dados pretendo que preencha com o primeiro dia do mês seguinte o campo data.

Tenho o código da seguinte forma:

HTML:

```
<div align="right">
     <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="alert_message"></div>
<table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Data</th>
      <th>Resp. de Turno</th>
      <th>Apoio</th>
      <th>Elementos ALA A</th>
      <th>Elementos ALA B</th>
      <th></th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  fetch_data();

  function fetch_data()
  {
   var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "oLanguage": {
    "sProcessing": "Aguarde enquanto os dados são carregados ...",
    "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
    "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro correspondente ao criterio encontrado",
    "sInfoEmtpy": "Exibindo 0 a 0 de 0 registros",
    "sInfo": "Exibindo de _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
    "sInfoFiltered": "",
    "sSearch": "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span>",
    "oPaginate": {
       "sFirst":    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward'></span>",
       "sPrevious": "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-backward'></span>",
       "sNext":     "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-forward'></span>",
       "sLast":     "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward'></span>"
     }
    }, 
    "order" : [],
    "ajax" : {
     url:"./fetchmapa",
     type:"POST"
    }
   });
  }
function novaData(d){
   var dia  = d.getDate().toString();
   dia = (dia.length == 1) ? '0'+dia : dia;
   var mes  = (d.getMonth()+1).toString();
   mes = (mes.length == 1) ? '0'+mes : mes;
   var ano = d.getFullYear();
   return dia+"-"+mes+"-"+ano;
}
 
  class CellDate {
    constructor(start_date) {
        this.date = start_date;
    }
    getNextDate() {
   //here the change for if condition     
   if ($('#user_data tbody tr') != null && $('#user_data tbody tr').length > 0) {
            var ultima_data = $("#user_data tbody tr:first td:first").text().trim().split("-");
            var ultimo_dia = +ultima_data[0];
            var ultimo_mes = +ultima_data[1];
            var ultimo_ano = +ultima_data[2];
            this.date.setDate(ultimo_dia);
            this.date.setMonth(ultimo_mes - 1);
            this.date.setYear(ultimo_ano);
            this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 1);
            console.log('if', this.date);
        } else {
            this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() + 1);
            this.date.setDate(1);
            console.log('else', this.date);
        }
        return novaData(this.date);
    }
}

  var DateIndexer = new CellDate(new Date(Date.now()));  

 $('#add').click(function(){

   var html = '<tr>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data1">'+DateIndexer.getNextDate()+'</td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data2"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data3"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data4"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data5"></td>';
   html += '<td><button type="button" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button></td>';
   html += '</tr>';
   $('#user_data tbody').prepend(html); //<--- right here

}); 

 $(document).on('click', '#insert', function(){
   var data = $('#data1').text();
   var responsavel = $('#data2').text();
   var apoio = $('#data3').text();
   var elementos = $('#data4').text();
   var elementos1 = $('#data5').text();
   if(data != '' && responsavel != '' && apoio != '' && elementos != '' && elementos1 != '')
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"./insert",
     method:"POST",
     data:{data:data, responsavel:responsavel, apoio:apoio, elementos:elementos, elementos1:elementos1},
     success:function(data)
     {
      $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
      $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
      fetch_data();
     }
    });
    setInterval(function(){
     $('#alert_message').html('');
    }, 5000);
   }
   else
   {
    alert("Os campos são de preencimento obrigatório!");
   }
  });
```

Desta forma se já existir dados na tabela de dados, preenche o campo data com a data do dia seguinte, mas se a tabela da base de dados estiver vazia e não retornar dados, recebo a seguinte mensagem na consola:

> if Invalid Date

Mas se retirar no `javascript` o `fetch_data();` já funciona, mas não mostra os dados que já existem na base de dados e vai sempre iniciar no primeiro dia do mês seguinte.

Deixo aqui os dois exemplos.
Exemplo com o problema:
Com o `fetch_data();` onde não inicia no primeiro dia do mês seguinte uma vez que não retorna dados [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/t0h3uq6a/1/)

Exemplo que funciona:
Sem o `fetch_data();`, mas se existir dados na base de dados não os mostra ao utilizador [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/t0h3uq6a/)

Pretendia colocar o exemplo que não funciona a funcionar, porque pretendo mostrar os dados ao utilizador, caso exista em base de dados.

Comment: Talvez a forma mais fácil de resolver seu problema seja você trazer direto da request a regra de data, deixa para o backend resolver e não o javascript. É até mais seguro, pois a data no javascript pode ser alterada pelo browser do usuário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É porque o Datatables, quando não há dados vindos do Ajax, cria automaticamente uma linha com **apenas uma coluna** informando que não existe dados a mostrar, e ao entrar no `if` irá tentar puxar uma data que não existe.

Para resolver isso, basta verificar no `if` se a primeira linha da tabela possui mais de uma coluna, ou seja, que pelo menos 1 linha com dados foram acrescentados na tabela, se existe mais de uma coluna na primeira linha:

```
if ($('#user_data tbody tr:first td').length > 1) {
```